# implement a custom TIFF decoder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, tiff

I want to implement a custom TIFF decoder in Flutter that supports multi-page TIFF images, including compression schemes like LZW and JPEG.
How can I display the decoded TIFF images in Flutter using a performant approach that allows for zooming and panning of the image?